# Capture and re-stream live video with java

Tags: java, sockets, http-live-streaming

I need to implement a solution in Java that connects to a CCTV server via TCP Socket, takes a live stream video from it and then takes that stream and outputs it to a spring boot endpoint (RTSP or other protocol) so that it can be shown in a web player.

The problem I have is that I do not quite know how to achieve that, maybe some can help. So far, I've got the following piece of code:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
            
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            // Login command
            outToServer.writeBytes(login);

            // Start LIVE video
            outToServer.writeBytes(live);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outStreamObj;
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] byteChunk = new byte[1024];

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            int c = input.read(byteChunk);
            while (c != -1) {
                buffer.write(byteChunk, 0, c);
                c = input.read(byteChunk); // If placed in its own loop, it will read forever (or until the stream stops) so it will never exit
                
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()));

                // create the object of ByteArrayOutputStream class
                outStreamObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                // write the image into the object of ByteArrayOutputStream class
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outStreamObj);

                // create the byte array from image
                byte[] byteArray = outStreamObj.toByteArray();

                // create the object of ByteArrayInputStream class
                // and initialized it with the byte array.
                ByteArrayInputStream inStreambj = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

                // read image from byte array
                BufferedImage newImage = ImageIO.read(inStreambj);

                // write output image
                ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", new File("outputImage.jpg"));
                System.out.println("Image generated from the byte array.");

            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ...

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ...
        }
```

So far, it works until `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()));`, where `image` is `null`. I am not even sure if this is correct. I wouldn't really want to save the image on disk any way, but for now it's okay i guess.

Basically, how it should work as follows:

- User visits a web page (Angular)
- The web player loads with a live stream url to the spring boot backend
- The spring boot backend connect further to the CCTV server via TCP (not possible via RTSP or other protocol) and sends the `live` command via the socket
- Within the same socket session the server starts pushing the live stream bytes
- The spring boot app takes these bytes and sends them further to the browser.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't the while loop end right after `c = input.read(byteChunk);` rather than after saving the entire image? You currently write a single byte to the buffer, then you're trying to load that buffer as an image.

Comment: You are right, but it does not work anyway as it continuously reads the stream, never goes further